# Adding deriving (Data) to standard types

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I would like to add `deriving (Data)` to standard types. After enabling the `StandaloneDeriving`, `FlexibleContexts`, `DeriveDataTypeable`, and `UndecidableInstances` extensions, ghc accepts

```
deriving instance Data Day => Data (Day)
```

However, if I do the same thing for `DiffTime` I get

```
TemperatureRecord.hs:30:0:
    The data constructors of `DiffTime' are not all in scope
      so you cannot derive an instance for it
    In the stand-alone deriving instance for
      `(Data DiffTime) => Data (DiffTime)'
```

I am doing all this to help autogenerate binary instances of standard types. So I have two questions:

1. How do I solve the error I am getting with `DiffTime`, and
2. What is the right way to make standard library types binary serializable in Haskell?

Comment: how is `DiffTime` imported into `TemperatureRecord`?

Comment: looks like `Data.Time.Clock`/`.Scale` doesn't export `MkDiffTime`, the constructor of `DiffTime`. without the constructors available for your use, the standard way of deriving would not work :/

Comment: @Jonathan Fischoff: yes. you are, imho, boned :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `time` package does not expose `MkDiffTime`, `DiffTime`'s constructor.

To create a `Data` instance, you would normally work with the type's constructors. Even if you are automatically deriving it, that's what the derived instance would do as well.

Luckily, this could be worked around, to some extent. You can extract the data from a `DiffTime` using `toRational`, and you can wrap a number in a `DiffTime` using `fromRational`. So it should be possible to "fake" a `Data` instance with a "fake" constructor. This would be done "manually" (no deriving).

As to why the constructor of `DiffTime` isn't exposed - this would be similar to the reasoning behind `private` in C++ et al. This gives the creators of `DiffTime` the freedom to change its implementation without breaking anything. Indeed, if they would change the structure, it won't break your "fake" `Data` instance and will not break your serialization format.

Answer (score -1):

I am a haskell newb, but I think you can do this to expose the constructor (and thus automatically derived Data)

> cabal unpack time

change

> newtype DiffTime = MkDiffTime Pico deriving (Eq,Ord

to

> data DiffTime = MkDiffTime Pico deriving (Eq,Ord

and cabal install seems to work

Comment: Nope. The visibility of a data constructor is determined by its appearance in the module’s export list.  It doesn’t make any difference whether the type was declared with `data` or `newtype`.